# How to move multiple files between folders in terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, directory, mv

How I can select all files in a directory and move them to another folder?

i have such directory: folder1/folder2/ [many different files here]

mv folder1 file3 - in this case only one file3 is moving in folder1

But i want to select all files in folder 2.

I try to print:

- /..
- ./*
  -whis -ls
  -other ways whis *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'mv' command to move files does support wildcard characters. Simply use `mv folder1/folder2/* <destination>`.

This command will move all files in folder1/folder2 to your specified destination.

Comment: mv: cannot stat 'folder1/folder2/*': No such file or directory

Comment: try it in different ways, names are correct

Comment: @SemjonShperling well that command depends at your current location, are you in the folder where folder1 resides? if not you have to specify the absolute path, not just the name of the folder (=relative path), e.g. `/home/<user>/folder1/folder2` or wherever your folder is located.

It would probably help you a lot to navigate and execute commands in the terminal if you learn about absolute and relative paths.

Comment: Thank you! Now, whis relative, long path) it works!

Answer (score 0):

If you really only want to move files and **not folders** within folder2 do this:

```
find /PATH/TO/FOLDER1/FOLDER2 -type f -exec mv {} /PATH/TO/DESTINATION/FOLDER/ \;
```

This will find all **files** in folder2 and move them to your new destination

/E: Other folders within folder2 will **not** be moved